# delete several permanent entries from arp table by command line

Tags: networking, bash, arp, xargs

I am trying to remove the permanent entries from my arp table. but the following command only removes those that are not permanent

```
ip -s -s neigh flush all
```

With the arp utility I was able to eliminate the permanent ones. Example:

```
arp -a
? (192.168.1.230) en d4:63:c6:11:22:33 [ether] PERM in enp2s0
arp -d 192.168.1.230
```

As there are several permanent entries I wanted to automate the command so that it removes any entry that contains "PERM":

```
arp -a | grep -i perm | grep -oP '(\d+\.){3}\d+' | xargs -I {} sudo arp -d {}
```

but it has an error:

```
xargs: sudo: ended with status 255; aborting
```

What did I do wrong? THK

**Update:**

solved bash to excluding the ip address of the computer where the command is executed

```
localip=192.168.1.11
arp -a | grep -i perm | grep -oP '(\d+\.){3}\d+' | grep -v $localip | xargs -I {} sudo arp -d {}
```

Thanks to all

Comment: Replace `sudo` with `echo sudo` and check its output.

Comment: out fine. it seems like maybe the problem is that the same machine I run the command from is PERM so I need to exclude it in the command

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your system appears to be a Linux system.

Along the commands `ifconfig`, `route` and `brctl`, the `arp` is in the category of "obsolete commands": it's using the deprecated (for network) *ioctl* kernel API to interact with the network stack.

Newer commands and tools, respectively `ip link` and `ip address`, `ip route`, `bridge` and finally [`ip neighbour`](https://manpages.debian.org/iproute2/ip-neighbour.8) (to replace `arp`), are the newer versions, using instead the [rtnetlink](https://manpages.debian.org/rtnetlink.7) kernel API. New features (eg: policy routing with `ip rule`) are usually only available on the newer API.

The permanent entry in OP's example could have been added with this command:

```
ip neighbour add 192.168.1.230 lladdr d4:63:c6:11:22:33 nud permanent dev enp2s0
```

with `nud` meaning:

> `nud STATE`
>       the state of the neighbour entry. nud is an abbreviation for 'Neighbour Unreachability Detection'. The state can take one of the
>   following values:
>
> `permanent`
>   the neighbour entry is valid forever and can be only be removed administratively.
>   [...]

These families of command have usually a more powerful syntax with some filter that can be applied to display or... bulk delete entries. Usually when a non-empty filter applies to the *show* subcommand (here: show permanent ARP entries):

```
# ip neighbour show nud permanent
192.168.1.230 dev enp2s0 lladdr d4:63:c6:11:22:33 PERMANENT
```

it will apply to the *flush* subcommand:

```
# ip neighbour flush nud permanent
# ip neighbour show nud permanent
#
```

---

Note:

While on my system `arp` is `/usr/sbin/arp` and I had this to rewrite the start with `/usr/sbin/arp`, your command appeared fine when run by a user with unlimited sudo rights. Anyway, if I understood your comment correctly, it underscores that trying to parse output mostly meant for human reading is not reliable.

---

UPDATE1: an example of controlled parsing with the JSON output

Recent enough iproute2 commands have a JSON output, which when combined with the [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) JSON parsing command can help a lot if an application or script doesn't have a more direct API available.

Example to retrieve all IP addresses in the ARP table matching a [locally administered](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address#/media/File:MAC-48_Address.svg) MAC address or a Xen or a VMware OUI:

```
# ip -json neighbour | jq -r '.[] | if .lladdr != null and ( .lladdr | test("^(.[26ae]|00:16:3e|00:05:69|00:0c:29|00:1c:14|00:50:56)","xi") )  then .dst else empty end'
```

---

UPDATE2: as commented, how to add an entry already temporarily, so potentially randomly, present?

An entry already present, cannot be added. It can be *changed* (if the entry is known to exist) or *replaced* (change it if existing, add it if not existing, so this will never answer EEXIST). This works for many other commands of the *iproute2* family.

Exemple:

```
# ping 192.168.1.231
PING 192.168.1.231 (192.168.1.231) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.1.2 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable

[...]

# ip neigh show nud failed
192.168.1.231 dev enp2s0  FAILED
# ip neigh add 192.168.1.231 lladdr 12:34:56:78:ab:cd nud permanent dev enp2s0
RTNETLINK answers: File exists
# ip neigh replace 192.168.1.231 lladdr 12:34:56:78:ab:cd nud permanent dev enp2s0
# ip neigh show nud permanent
192.168.1.231 dev enp2s0 lladdr 12:34:56:78:ab:cd PERMANENT
```

Comment: Your method is definitely better than mine. Thank you